# How do I find a table in DataGrip

Tags: sql, sybase, datagrip

Using JetBrains' DataGrip 2017.3.4 I have it linked to a Sybase TSQL database. All I wish to do is find a table in it so that I can find the structure.

I have selected all nodes and opened them 3 times - once for the dbo, once for the tables and procedures and once for the list of tables and procedures - and can now select the top line and "simply type the table I am a looking for", or so I am told.

If looking for *tb_AllSaints*, this does not seem to be a problem. However, when looking for *tb_ZZTop*, the table *tb_MaxZZTop* keeps "helpfully" popping up first and there doesn't seems to be a way to find the "next" table in the list. If it is a particularly long list, scrolling through by hand is murder.

The alternative, Ctrl-N, will enable me to select data from any table but I cannot get the table structure at all.

Help...

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions.

1. When using Speed Search with *tb_ZZTop*, press Down arrow - it will navigate you to the next match. There are some issues there, not always works: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5927
   If in your case it also doesn't work, please, comment with the screenshot there.
2. When using *Ctrl+N* navigation (it can be handy if the tree is not expanded or you have no idea where your table is), click on DDL button in the data editor. There you will see the DDL, where structure information is stored.

Comment: Found it, and that's brilliant - thanks! Some tables are HUGE though and to use the DDL button you must open them first. Can opening the tables be "bypassed" please so that you only see the structure of the table?

Comment: Yes, you can! Ctrl+N -> type the name of the table. Don't forget to turn this setting off! https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/whatsnew/img/2018.1/Navigation.png

Comment: Re: opening tables to DDL. I can't find the setting from 2018 in the New UI. But you can still select a table and Ctrl + B to open DDL.

Comment: Yes, we removed the setting to make everything straightforward